# E: The package linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 18.04, kernel

This is my first question. I get the above error for all sudo apt install commands and other commands as well. There are not many such errors that I could find online and the answers to those problems don't work for me. Thank you in advance.

I get the following message when I run
`sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic`

```
 Reading package lists... 6%
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
    E: The package linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

and the following message when I run
`sudo apt purge code`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Download the package `linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic` from launchpad.net in order to reinstall it.

Comment: Both of these questions have been answered many, many times. "*Those answers did not work for me*" is too vague to offer useful advice. It's better to post the complete input and output demonstrating how something did not work.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for answering . Any sudo apt command is not working ... I could not find the said package on launchpad. There are similar packages but they don't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong ? please tell what more is required other than the input and output in the question. I will update the post with the same. Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply solved it after installing the correct package